# Get nginx htpasswd user

Tags: javascript, nginx, .htpasswd

I try to log all current users that watched the site. 
Using the .htpasswd on nginx and created several preconfigured users.
The user:password combinations were shared to them.

Is it possible to get the current logged in user from htpasswd?

Or alternativly to log the user logins?